# Button not working in infoWindow on Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this google map which is working, I want to add a button on infowindow which somehow is not working. Though the function is defined but still throw error
http://jsfiddle.net/mpgxn53q/

```
<div id="apptMap"></div>
//the js code
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

var locations = [["158845-001 - Adas Israel Congregation",38.9369545,-77.0575097,1],["163888-137 - Construction LLC",43.1765812,-84.6986701,2.0],["163888-155 - Construction LLC",43.1765812,-84.6986701,3.0],["167176-007 - GLDB MTM10 GLR016",42.4894512,-95.5449508,4.0],["167195-003 - 91622 DB A4",42.8275053,-84.5717997,5.0],["167195-002 - 91622 DB A4",42.8275053,-84.5717997,6.0],["167176-005 - GLDB MTM10 GLR016",42.0023,-93.6110955,7.0],["167176-004 - GLDB MTM10 GLR016",42.0023,-93.6110955,8.0]];

var map;
var markers = [];

function init(){
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('apptMap'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.0023,-93.6110955),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var num_markers = locations.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++) {  
    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat:locations[i][1], lng:locations[i][2]},
      map: map,
      html: locations[i][0],
      id: i,
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(){
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        id: this.id,
        content:this.html +'<button onclick="mapsZoomMarker('+i+')">Click me</button>',
        position:this.getPosition()
      });
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function(){
        markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
      });
      this.setVisible(false);
      infowindow.open(map);
    });
  }
}
function mapsZoomMarker(wnMarker){
            map.setCenter(markers[wnMarker].getPosition());
            map.setZoom(15);
        } 
init();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with scopes, and that's because of that how you wrote your script. I am not going to rewrite your script, but I will give you solution for your exact situation.

You need to define your function `mapsZoomMarker` in global scope (window object) like this:

```
window.mapsZoomMarker = function (wnMarker){
    map.setCenter(markers[wnMarker].getPosition());
    map.setZoom(15);
}
```

And there is also a mistake, in the function which is called when the marker is clicked. When you assign the html for the popup like this

```
content: this.html +'<button onclick="mapsZoomMarker('+i+')">Click me</button>'
```

the `i` variable is already set to `8`, so instead of that just use `this.id` like this:

```
content: this.html +'<button onclick="mapsZoomMarker('+this.id+')">Click me</button>'
```

And this is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rn27f05v/

Comment: Got it about the window scope, but what about the index? Loop is already starting from 0, and same index value is being passed to function. Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually as I said, the way how your are constructing the markers is totally not ok. Your function which creates the markers is called when the `for` cycle is finished, and when it's finished the `i` variable is set to `8`, so every popup is assigned with this code `<button onclick="mapsZoomMarker(8)">Click me</button>`

Comment: Ah, I see. Rather than decrease the index by 1, I had to change value being passed. Instead of i, now pass this.id which brings the correct value

Comment: Yes you are right, I've just updated the answer, but you got it from my comment first. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

I will propose a solution that I think is best for what you want. Instead call function inside var infowindow, you can only define a variable to put content your want.

You can change you var infowindow to:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    id: this.id,
    content: content, //here the variable that call your content
    position:this.getPosition()
});
```

So... above your `google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(){...` you can add:

```
var content = '<button onclick="mapsZoomMarker('+i+')">Click me</button>';
```

This way the click action will work.

Hope this tip help you.